# Substr & Strrchr in a value

Tags: php

I have the following form input :

```
<input value="<?php echo isset($item['product_id']) ? $item['product_id']: ''; ?>" type="text" data-type="productCode" name="data[InvoiceDetail][<?php echo $key;?>][product_id]" id="itemNo_<?php echo $key+1?>" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="return tabE(this,event);">
```

The input auto populates with the product code, and looks like this :
Manufacturer:Submanufacturer:etc:etc:model

I used the following code :

```
<?php 
            $productid = isset($item['product_id']) ? $item['product_id'] : '';
            $fproductid = substr(strrchr($productid, ":"), 1);
        ?>
```

and converted the above code to such :

```
<input value="<?php echo $fproductid; ?>" type="text" data-type="productCode" name="data[InvoiceDetail][<?php echo $key;?>][product_id]" id="itemNo_<?php echo $key+1?>" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="return tabE(this,event);">
```

with the output being :
model

However, when I save the form, and reload, the fields are blank?  How can I save the form with the original data(with manufacturers), but only display the model in the user entered fields?

Comment: Presumably the problem is not in `substr`, but in database saving?

Comment: @u_mulder correct, I am trying to use substr to make viewing possible, but I dont want it to affect the contents of whats saved to the db, only what the user sees

Comment: Then you can have a couple of fields - one that user sees with `model`. And another one, `type="hidden"` I suppose, with full content.

Comment: @u_mulder It is a little bit more complicated than that - when the user types in the field, a jquery autocomplete script goes in effect to pull data from the database based on what they type

Comment: And what? For `autocomplete` event there should be some callback in which you can parse result and put full string into one field and `model`-part into visible one.

Comment: @u_mulder I am honestly not too familiar with the autocomplete script, followed a tutorial to use it - If I posted, would you be able to help me find where the parsing should go?

Comment: Is it `jquery-autocomplete`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107177/discussion-between-steven-and-u-mulder).

Comment: Then example https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data is what you need.

Comment: @u_mulder I apologize, must have misunderstood - it uses jquery, and it is an autocomplete script, the link you sent me is not the same thing as far as i can tell, i posted the code in the discussion forum